# Cannot login to Software Engineering via Yahoo OpenID

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, yahoo

I've been trying to logon to Software Engineering via Yahoo OpenID for the last 20 minutes, at the very least 15+ attempts, and it isn't working.

I am brought to a `open.login.yahoo.com/openid/yaddayadda` URL that freezes on a black while screen, and that's it.

I did manage to get through another Stack Exchange site, which logged me in for all sites, but still, maybe it is something that needs to be looked into.

Answer (score 1):

I tried logging in with Yahoo last week and had issues as well. The code's all shared across the sites, though, so I'm about 95% sure the issue is somewhere on their end as a result.